# How to implement slide out/swipe menu like in facebook app in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone, swipe

Does anybody know where can I get a slide out/swipe menu like in facebook app for my windows phone app. I really want to implement such functionality but can't find any control with similar behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved. Great tutorial:
http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/07/30/facebook-like-settings-pane-with-gestures-windows-phone/